# can I migrate a bzr central repository trunk to a new location?

Tags: migration, repository, bazaar

I set up an central repository in my home directory.

I set it up in my home directory and would like to move it from /home/$USER to /home/share/.

For reference, here are the details of the initial setup for reference following the directions in the  [bzr documentation](http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/latest/en/tutorials/centralized_workflow.html):

```
#establish the central repository
mkdir project
mkdir project/dev
bzr init-repo --no-trees sftp://server/home/$USER/project
bzr init sftp://server/home/$USER/project/trunk

#make local repository
bzr init-repo project
cd project
bzr branch sftp://server/home/$USER/project/trunk dev

#copy files, add to bzr, commit
mv files project/dev/
bzr add
bzr commit -m 'initial import'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can move your **central** repository and all branches inside it with just plain `mv` command of your system.

But you'll need to update all your local working branches to remember new location after move of central repository. You can do it with following commands:

```
bzr pull --remember sftp://server/home/share/project/trunk
bzr push --remember sftp://server/home/share/project/trunk
```

Or if you're using checkouts (created on local computer with `bzr checkout` command) then update master branch location with command:

```
bzr switch --force sftp://server/home/share/project/trunk
```